capture event for window restore in tcl/tk
My application is written in tcl/tk. When a primary window is restored from taskbar then i need to bring secondary windows (dialogs) to the top (on top of primary window). i need to capture window restore event in tcl/tk in order to do that. I tried Map/Unmap event capture but it is not fired when window is restored.

Normal practice is to make secondary windows (dialogs) transient on the primary window (container). By doing that, the dialogs will automatically iconify and deiconify with the container.
toplevel .t -width 400 -height 400
toplevel .t.s
wm transient .t.s .t

A side effect is that no icon is shown in the taskbar for the dialog windows and they get centered on the container window. If you object to that, you can do it yourself by using the Map and Unmap events. You did not show any code, so it's difficult to say why you concluded those events don't fire. This works for me (linux x86_64, Tk 9.0.0):
toplevel .t -width 400 -height 400
toplevel .t.s

bind .t <Map> {wm deiconify .t.s}
bind .t <Unmap> {wm iconify .t.s}

Note that widgets inside the toplevel will normally include their toplevel window in the bindtags. This means that the Map and Unmap events bound to the toplevel will fire for each widget inside the toplevel. To prevent a multitude of calls to your event handler you may want to check for which widget the Map/Unmap event fires and only take action when the event refers to the toplevel itself. Or you can bind the Map/Unmap events to a selected widget inside the toplevel. Which option to pick depends on the situation.
Addendum:
After additional information that you are running this on Rocky 8 (among others), I created a virtual machine running Rocky 8. Either the problem is that it is using Wayland or the window manager is just an abomination.
Whatever the reason may be, Tk is kept completely in the dark about what is going on. When a toplevel is minimized, either via user interaction with the window manager or even with the wm iconify command, wm state still reports "normal".
The only event that fires when a toplevel window is restored from the taskbar is . But using that event to deiconify any secondary windows also doesn't work, because those windows are not iconified, as far as Tk is aware.
I'm afraid that using transient windows may be the only way to achieve what you ask.

i tried your code (without transient) on centos7 and rocky8. on both OS it did not work as expected. I minimized t and s both window to the taskbar and then clicked on taskbar button for t to restore it. t got restored (deiconified) but s did not get deiconified and automatically placed on top of t.

Placed on top is trickier; stacking order requests aren't always respected by window managers (due to massive abuse in the past). I'd try making the windows a group, making the workers transient for the main window, adding the bindings, and generally a lot of experimentation.
